# nx format:check doesn't seem to actually check formatting

Tags: lint, prettier, monorepo, nx-monorepo

Being new in nx, I'm trying to implement linting

my core package.json has `"prettier": "^2.8.1",` in devDependencies

when I mess up with formatting in my apps/libs, i.e. mix double quotes and single quotes, running `npx nx format:check` doesn't yield any errors neither fixes formatting

How exactly this command supposed to work? According to docs, the only info is `Check for un-formatted files` which it apparently fails to do, although I do see the file in question in (successful) output

Answer (score 0):

I got confused by seeing the output enumerating files. Apparently, this is the expected behaviour: most of my files were not formatted "right" (according to the current prettierrc I used) and the tool printing those file names did print in into stderr in fact.

It just looked like a successful execution, when ran manually.